# node version on $PATH issue on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, path, webpacker

Having problems when trying to push my Rails 5.1 app to Heroku. `rake:assets:precompile` fails with

```
Webpacker requires Node.js >= 6.0.0 and you are using 0.10.30
```

I've posted before on this but haven't been able to resolve it, and am now going round in circles.  I'm told it looks like an issue with my $PATH and I need to make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in my $PATH. It looks like it is. I can also run node and print from the console. I can also see the version of node I'm running, so I'm now at a loss. One thing that does look obviously wrong, is that amount of 'stuff' in the $PATH. Could this be causing the issue?

```
Simons-MBP:~ Simon$ echo $PATH
/Users/Simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/Users/Simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/Users/Simon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/Simon/.rvm/bin
Simons-MBP:~ Simon$ node
> console.log('hello node')
hello node
undefined
> 
(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
> 
Simons-MBP:~ Simon$ node -v
v8.9.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the error is because of your local version of Node, but the Node version on Heroku. 
See how to specify your [Node Engine on Heroku's blog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node)

If that doesn't work, you may need to specify a [Buildpack(one compatible with both Ruby & Node)](https://github.com/rtgibbons/heroku-buildpack-ruby-nodejs), however, I believe you may only need to specify the engine.